# JavaScript- Remove object from parent array with an object's method

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, circular-reference

I have a parent object that stores an array of children and calls some of their methods.

```
var Parent = function ()
{
     this.children = []
     this.addChildren();
}

Parent.prototype.addChildren = function ()
{
     for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         this.children.push(new Child());
     }

     this.alterChildren();
}

Parent.prototype.alterChildren = function ()
{
     this.children.forEach(function (child)
     {
         if (child.hasSomeProperty.foo)
         {
              child.alter();
         }
     });
}
```

Then there are the child objects. When a certain event happens with them, I need them to be effectively destroyed and I null properties that the parent relies on.

```
var Child = function ()
{
   this.hasSomeProperty = {
      foo: 'bar'
   };
}

Child.prototype.onDestroyEvent = function ()
{
   this.hasSomeProperty = null;
}
```

I then want to remove this child from the parent's child array and have the child garbage collected. Is there an elegant way to do this without circular references or breaking my existing structures?

Comment: Why are you worried about Garbage collection?

Comment: I omitted the specific situation here, but the Child object actually contains a Phaser sprite that has methods called on it in the game loop. I need to destroy the Phaser sprite (because it's expensive to have it there and unused), and then have the child destroyed in the parent array to avoid errors.

Comment: The garbage collector will figure this out.

Comment: But not if the child isn't spliced out of the array, correct? The child still exists and needs to go in order for an error not to be thrown when the parent calls child.sprite.doSomething()

Comment: Circular references are only problematic for purely reference-counting GCs. JavaScripts GC is a lot more capable. See [the MDN on memory management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Reference-counting_garbage_collection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the child to send a message to the parent then the child needs to have a reference to the parent.

```
Parent.prototype.addChildren = function ()
{
    for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        this.children.push(new Child(this));
    }
    this.alterChildren();
}
Parent.prototype.removeChild = function (child)
{
    var i = this.children.indexOf(child);
    return this.children.splice(i, 1);
}
```

and

```
var Child = function (parent)
{
   this.parent = parent;
   this.hasSomeProperty = {
      foo: 'bar'
   };
}

Child.prototype.destroy = function ()
{
   this.hasSomeProperty = null;    
   this.parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this creating a circular reference which is bad?

Comment: [Cycles are not a problem anymore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Cycles_are_not_a_problem_anymore)